# Does anyone used a zoom g1x four with bias fx?

Tags: electric-guitar, effects-pedal

So I always wanted to cover marooned by pink floyd but it never hit home for me since I don't own a pitch shifter pedal I only use bias fx2 via my audio interface I was keen to buy this cheap zoom multi effects so I can use it's built in pitch shifter but then I realized that you can only put up to 5 block of units in your signal chain, so with a amp and cab it only left you with 3 other effect which isn't enough if you are going to get that tone

I was wondering that does anyone ever used this multi effect with bias fx? Without messing up the guitar tone or signals?

In theory you should be able to use noise gate/comp/drive/amp/cabin on zoom and get your reverb and echo on the bias fx

But I'm not sure if it will work out alright in reality

Edit: in case of me not being clear enough with my question since both of these devices (bias and zoom) are digitally manipulating the signal from your guitar I was wondering the result (the quality of the sound and tone of your guitar) would be usable for recording at home  or live performance or we will get a very thin weak unsatisfying sound at the end 
I know the quality of your tone and sound of your guitar is subjective matter  but I was hopeful to find someone who used these 2 together and ask him about the end result

Comment: Could you perhaps make your title more reflective of what you are actually trying to achieve, rather than asking if anyone else uses something? That just not searchable for future visitors. One would assume that the answer, if any, will come from someone who does use it, as opposed to someone who has never heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

They will work beautifully together. The signals don't know that one is digital and one is analog. You can mix any digital with any analog and any digital with digital. It's just sound waves passing through your cables. So there's no compatibility issue. As long as the cable ends match, you're good. It really comes down to the quality of your effects.